# .NET Can't find performance category on local machine unless I specify local machine name

Tags: c#, .net, windows, performancecounter

If I look in the performance monitor on a given machine, I'll see a given perf counter, lets say with the category "perfCategory" and the name "perfCounterName". In C#, I ultimately would like to be able to write to this perf counter. However, I'm hitting an issue where .NET can't even find the category unless I specify a computer name (which I then can't write to because it says I can't write to a remote perf counter, even when I use the FQDN of the local machine). For example, when I run the below code, the Console.WriteLine outputs True, but at the 3rd line I get an InvalidOperationException: Category does not exist.  According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecountercategory(v=vs.110).aspx), not specifying a computer name uses the local machine. Could there be some sort of permission issue here?

```
var test = new PerformanceCounterCategory("perfCategory", "computerNameOfLocalMachine");
Console.WriteLine(test.CounterExists("perfCounterName");
var test2 = new PerformanceCounterCategory("perfCategory");
```

Output
: True
: InvalidOperationException: Category does not exist

Comment: Have you tried using `"."` for the computer name

Comment: @Übercoder Just tried it - still get "Category does not exist". Just to reiterate, when I go to the performance monitor and select <Local computer>, I see this category/perf counter.

Comment: Did you see this [CATEGORY DOES NOT EXIST. (YES IT DOES)](https://thwack.solarwinds.com/thread/43987)?

Comment: Or this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745176/category-does-not-exist-creating-performance-counter-for-msmq-queue)?